# DropwizardAppRule ClassRule does not release connections after test completion

Tags: java, junit, jersey, dropwizard

I have some integration tests for a RESTful application written in Java using Dropwizard. The test suite runs fine until eventually it hangs and I get an exception with `C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager`: `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections`

I identified that the connections are not being cleaned up after each test using `C3P0Registry.getPooledDataSources()`, but I misdiagnosed the problem as not closing my jersey response entities, as detailed here: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5255

Many of the tests are checking for just a status code, so it made sense to me that this would be happening (In the link it states: "If you don't read the entity, then you need to close the response manually by `response.close()`"). However, after fixing this problem and ensuring that each entity was closed, I'm still getting persistent connections between tests.

I'm using `DropwizardAppRule` as a Class Rule and after creation at the beginning and end of each test run, I can call to close the client that is associated with the rule, but the connections remain open. My `C3P0ConnectionPool` gains 3 connections per test class that is run and I can't figure out a way to stop it from growing with each new class that is added.

ClassRule snippet:

```
    @ClassRule
    public static final DropwizardAppRule<MicroServiceCoreConfiguration> RULE =
            new DropwizardAppRule<>(App.class, ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath("./config.yml"));
```

Will update with any information that is requested!